# R.java File Showing Error

Tags: android, r.java-file

```
public static final int @+id/scrollView=0x7f08000f;
```

This line is making error in my R.java file. I have tried deleting that R.jav file and rebuild it but still its the same error on these tokens

> @+id

This is my error :

> Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Why is this token generated in my file? I have also checked my xml files and there is no mistake nor any error.

Comment: Don't just delete R.java. Use Project -> Clean. If it still does it, post the exact error.

Comment: @Squonk.. I had tried project clean but nothing happened.. See my edit for the error.

Comment: I once had similiar errors. The int should be generated as there is a `ScrollView` somewhere in your xml files. Rebuilding (on Eclipse with Project > Clean) should normally work - have you checked the XML doesn't contain any single quote signs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238324/android-r-java-will-not-update?rq=1

Comment: @Squonk.. below solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you have wrongly written the id in your XMl in wrong format

Your id in your XML is like this

```
android:id="@+id/@+id/scrollView"
```

You need to make the following change to make it working

```
 android:id="@+id/scrollView"
```

Comment: Good catch although you missed the forward-slash from `android:id="@+idscrollView"`

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
public static final int scrollView=0x7f08000f;
```

in the R.java file. The @+id/scrollView is an xml attribute. Look at your xml when you create an id for any view.

Answer (score -1):

If you find error in R.java file, **check your all .xml files!** There must be some errors in any of those file!

Same thing happened with me..! And I fixed it following this way only!